# log file path for windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows service which does some work and in which I am also trying to write the logs to a file.
Inside my `app.Config`, I have a section to define the source of the log file:

In the `Serivce1.cs`, I have define the logger as:

```
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private static TraceSource ServiceLogger = new TraceSource("ServiceTrace");
```

Inside other methods, I write to the log file by the following code,

```
ServiceLogger.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "{0} : Running", DateTime.Now);
```

There is not an exception inside the windows event viewer and the service is running with local system (broad previliges) but I am not able to find the log after the installation of this service. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here  is a sample demo for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

Configurations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx